# XAML:The attachable property VisualStateGroups was not found in type VisualStateManager

Tags: wpf, xaml, attached-properties

I'm using VS2008 EE SP1 + WPF + XAML.
In the beginning I added a reference to it:

```
xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"
```

I'm getting this error  while compilation:

```
<vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>  
   <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <vsm:VisualTransition To="MouseOver" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                            <vsm:VisualTransition To="Pressed" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                        <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                            </Storyboard>
```

Does anybody know the reason and possible workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will not work in a .NET 3.5sp1 WPF application.

[VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager(VS.95).aspx) and the related classes were introduced as part of Silverlight 3.  It is not part of WPF in 3.5sp1, but is being added to WPF in Version 4.